# Is it known what would have happened in later seasons of Zoo?

Tags: zoo

[*Zoo*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3250026), a 2015 sci-fi show loosely based on the eponymous novel by James Patterson, got cancelled after three seasons, presumably due to low audience.

Season 2 picked up right where season 1 left off, so I suppose the same diptych pattern was intended for seasons 3 and 4, as one does not simply end a series

> by remote-crashing a plane onto the *one* wall which was keeping monstruous hybrids from invading the United States, thus opening an Air Force One-sized breach in it, based on the sole premise that the season's villain would indeed return a baby back.

For instance, when [*Revolution*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2070791/) got cancelled, the crew patched up a comic which tied up loose ends from season 2. I did not find such a thing for *Zoo*<sup>1</sup>, but I thought **maybe the showrunners later revealed what they had in mind, in an interview perhaps?** My Googling doesn't bring anything up so far, but at least one piece of season 4 material was strongly implied by

> the IADG agent's dog coming back to life. I want zombie hybrids!

Surely the people who wrote the incredible amount of absurdness<sup>2</sup> the third season had to offer, thought of yet even more goofy madness for the next seasons?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>There's a graphic novel for *Zoo* but it's related to the novel, not the show (which doesn't have much to do with the book anyways).</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Don't get me wrong, I absolutely loved the part where the team tucked the hybrid-decoy into a sports car in which they didn't know the bad guy was hiding, and then threw it into an erupting volcano, and then absolutely needed the same bad guy to confess whatever crime, and realized what they had done by reviewing CCTV footage. Guilty pleasure.</sub>

Comment: do you have a link for the Revolution comic? I really liked that show and was disappointed that it ended.

Comment: @Ring sure, it's on Facebook - see [What happens after nanobots invade Philadelphia?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/195993/98028). The comic is quite great at providing an actual ending, by the way.